# JHipster - How to override Bootstrap styles?

Tags: bootstrap-4, jhipster

**Goal**

Change td style in the global.css file. For example:

```
th, td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Issue**

It doesn't work. However, I tried to apply css styles using other selectors in this global.css file including input and it works.

```
input {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Could you tell me what is the best method to override bootstrap styles in JHipster? Why I can't access td but I can access input?

Thanks,

Manu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the !important keyword in the global.css. Maybe it's not the best way. If you have a better answer, please be welcome to post it. Thanks!

```
.table-centered td, th {
text-align: center !important;
vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```